# Individual Character Pyramid in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

If my program is given a string, it should output the characters in the following way:

```
h
he
hel
help
```

How do I do this in python? I tried this; but it doesn't print them in the pyramid format:

```
  for i in range(1,n+1):
          for j in range(0,i):
               print "HELP",
          print ""
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?:

```
x = "HELP"
for letter in xrange(len(x)+1):
    print x[0:letter].lower()
```

Comment: I like the fact that you actually bothered with `lower` instead of assuming that he was wrong with the capitalization

Comment: Thanks, i also wanted it to be capable of being applied to other words as opposed to hard coding it simply for "HELLO".

Comment: Thanks...CAPs is not a matter here, we can use both lower/upper

Answer (score -1):

```
cnt = 0
str1 = "help"
while True:
    if len(str1)<cnt:
        break
    print (str1[:cnt])
    cnt += 1
```

It's a hardcoded one. Not elegant. But for you it's the best I think, I guess you're new in Python. Slicing the string part by part

Answer (score -1):

```
x = "help"
for i in range(1,len(x)+1): 
    print x[0:i]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
print "\n".join(map(lambda x:"HELP"[:x],range(5)))
```

is one way you could do it